# ASP.net basic help with ASCX user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

Trying to build my own user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TabMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="TabMenu" %>

<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="tabWrapper">
        <div class="tab tabSelected"><a href="artworkHome.aspx">Home</a></div>
        <div class="tab"><a href="#">Create New</a></div>
        <div class="tab"><a href="#">Help!</a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lol"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Panel>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TabMenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string TabGroup { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.TabGroup == "Artwork")
        {
            lol.Text = "LOL!";
        }

    }
}
```

This shows fine when used as such:

```
<CrystalControls:TabMenu runat="server" TabGroup="Artwork" />
```

Except that "LOL!" isn't showing.  I'm probably using properties incorrectly etc, I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Where is the Literal with the ID of `lol` located? In your user control or in the .aspx page the control has been placed in?

Comment: @Dan The literal is in the code above, in the TabMenu.ascx file.  Even if I remove the condition, it's not showing anything if I set it's text in the codebehind of the ascx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example, but its all working fine, i do get LOL! in the literal. 
If you debug the code, and set a braekpoint on the check if Tabgroup == "ArtWork", you can check the value of TabGroup, maybe it is not set yet ?

Comment: Even if I take out the conditional and just set the text, it still doesn't show :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your control is coded correctly and works fine. I suspect the reason you are not seeing the LOL! text is due to something in your HTML or CSS obscuring it. For instance, you might have `display:none` on one of your tabs. Try looking at the page source and seeing if the LOL! text is in it - I bet it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Page_Load is not an event that is automatically wired up for user controls, see [autoeventwireup](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/16/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx), personally i hate the idea of subscribing to my own events anyway, you should override the provided virtual methods where possible..

Try this...

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{    
    if (this.TabGroup == "Artwork")          
    {              
         lol.Text = "LOL!";          
    } 
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

or even this if its likely that the user of the control could change the TabGroup during the page lifecyle..

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{    
    if (this.TabGroup == "Artwork")          
    {              
         lol.Text = "LOL!";          
    } 
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Comment: I've put the override in but it's still not rendering anything on the control

Comment: questioner has `AutoEventWireup` set to `true` in his `@Control` directive (it defaults to `true` anyway in C# pages and controls), so overriding `OnLoad()` is not necessary -- the event should fire.

Comment: I guess it must, we never use autoeventwireup so i overlooked that ;-)